# Issue Installing Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Disclaimer: I am very new to Python. I am trying to install scikit-learn using pip in windows powershell. Everytime I do this, I receive the following message:

'''
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:
'''

More specifically, access is denied for vcomp140.dll.

I have tried many forums, but no luck.

Anything helps!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to install scikit withoud admin rights? Try right click on powershell and select "run as administrator".

However, I would not use windows for development. Rather look into virtualization and run a linux VM through Virtual Box where you will be able to customize more and probably get better support. Also, you will not have to mess with the host system so anytime you update your project and that fails, you can roll back to a snapshot of your VM and not have to fix or reinstall the whole host system. VirtualBox + Ubuntu best solution. An alternative would be a WSL2 + Ubuntu. But I do not trust Microsoft, too many intermediate issues that will hold you back. I would go with the VBox + Ubuntu (or your preferred linux distro).

Comment: I did see admin rights suggestions. I have tried that, but still no luck.I might try the virtual box suggestion.

Comment: Unless you have to develop for windows because a customer tells you so, do not spend your time with fixing windows issues. This suggestion might not be helpful, just trying to save you time if you are doing this outside of some professional constraint.